# Remove item in list if adjacent

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, zip

I have a list of type Fruit.
I'm looking to remove APPLE, BANANA pairs, only if they're adjacent and in that order.

For example:

```
val basket: Fruitbasket = List(PEAR, APPLE, BANANA, CHERRY)
```

Reduced to:

```
LIST(PEAR, CHERRY)
```

Another example:

```
val basket2: Fruitbasket = List(PEAR, APPLE, PEAR, BANANA, CHERRY)
```

Would not reduce and remains as:

```
List(PEAR, APPLE, PEAR, BANANA, CHERRY)
```

I understand zipping with its tail is a way to compare adjacent elements, but what is the best way to filter and unzip?

```
basket.zip(basket.tail)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could just use a tail-recursive function and pattern matching:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def filterOut(basket: List[String]): List[String] = {

    @tailrec
    def go(basket: List[String], acc: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = {

      basket match {
        case "APPLE" :: "BANANA" :: xs => go(xs, acc)
        case x :: xs => go(xs, x :: acc)
        case Nil => acc.reverse
      }
    }

    go(basket)
}


filterOut(List("PEAR", "APPLE", "BANANA", "CHERRY"))  // List("PEAR", "CHERRY")
filterOut(List("PEAR", "APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA", "CHERRY")) // List("PEAR", "APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA", "CHERRY")
```

Comment: Don't you think that this solution is kinda overheaded?

Comment: It's very probable, that there are better, more succinct solutions. This one is just the first thing that came to my head.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `indexOfSlice` method.
Here is my implementaiton:

```scala
def censoreSeq0[T](col: Seq[T], censored:Seq[T]):Seq[T] = if (censored.isEmpty) col else {
  col.indexOfSlice(censored) match {
    case -1 => col
    case x => col.take(x) ++ censoreSeq0(col.drop(x+censored.length), censored)
  }
}
```

In this fiddle there is more implementations, that does it bit differently:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/EgQ7FCT/3

Comment: `if (censored.isEmpty) col else ...` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that this is kinda utility method, you can you mutable list underhood for better performance. Example stolen from Krzysztof Atłasik answer.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def filterOut(basket: List[String]): List[String] = {
  @tailrec
  def go(basket: List[String], acc: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]): ListBuffer[String] = {
    basket match {
      case Nil => acc
      case "APPLE" :: "BANANA" :: xs => go(xs, acc)
      case x :: xs => go(xs, acc += x)
    }
  }

  go(basket).result()
}


filterOut(List("PEAR", "APPLE", "BANANA", "CHERRY"))  // List("PEAR", "CHERRY")
filterOut(List("PEAR", "APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA", "CHERRY")) // List("PEAR", "APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA", "CHERRY")
```